# How do I pass arguments to inside of callback function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

This is my code

```
for (var x in items) {
    var name = items[x].Name;
    var hotelID = 1;
    var sql = mysql.format('INSERT INTO Item(name, hotelID) VALUES(?, ?)', [name, hotelID]);
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
           //Below x is updated by the loop.
           console.log(item[x].Name);
        });
```

I want to get the value of `x` right before the con.query() call, but here the x is updated by the `for` loop before the callback is completed. How do i do that??

Comment: Use `let x` instead of `var x`.

Comment: ... and may switch to `async` + `await`

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks, worked. please put it as an answer

Comment: @Alnitak what happened when i used the `let`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've identified, in a asynchronous callback "the x is updated by the for loop before the callback is completed".

The solution it to use the ES6 syntax `let` instead of `var`.  Variables declared thus are correctly bound within the callback to the value they had when the callback was registered because a new variable is created for each iteration of the loop instead of using the single `var` which is hoisted to the top of the function.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained *why* `let` acted that way (like the accepted answer on the duplicate question)

Comment: @Quentin it would, but I don't actually know, I just know that it does  :p  NB, this is community wiki, so I'm not here for the rep.

Comment: "I don't actually know" — I just pointed you at an explanation, you could read it!

Comment: @Quentin I did - it's not that great an explanation IMHO.  I thought you were suggesting that there was something more mysterious about it than the scoping.